# Find a Cartesian equation of $r = 4\cos\theta$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I was able to figure the substitutions inside the equation, but I'm stuck with the equation's manipulation that will give me the solution. What would be my next step?

$$r = 4\cos\theta$$
$$r^2 = 4r\cos\theta \tag{multiply both sides by $r$}$$
$$x^2+y^2 = 4x \tag{$r^2=x^2+y^2\quad r\cos\theta=x$}$$
$$x^2+y^2-4x=0 $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already done most of the work and undoubtedly the hardest part of it, the secret is: complete the square:

$$x^2+y^2-4x=0\iff (x-2)^2+y^2=4$$

Comment: So basically I need to look for a constant to add to both sides that will allow me to complete the square? Or should I just add the coefficient of $x$ to both sides?

Comment: It's a basic HS technique, @wizardo : $$ax^2+bx=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}\;,\;\;a\neq 0$$